# jqPlot: Define labels for a bar chart with multiple series

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

In the jqPlot documentation for [Data Point Labels](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/point-labels.php) it gives an example (see third example) for defining custom point labels for a bar chart with one series.

I need to do this, but for a bar chart with multiple series. Here is what I tried. I used the documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#$.jqplot.PointLabels.labels).

```
  var line1 = [14, 32, 41];
  var line2 = [15, 33, 42];
  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2], {
    title: 'Bar Chart with Point Labels', 
    seriesDefaults: {renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer},
    series:[{
        pointLabels: {
        show: true,
        labels: [
          ['fourteen', 'thirty two', 'forty one'],
          ['fifteen', 'thirty three', 'forty two']
        ]
      }
    }],
    axes: {
      xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer },
      yaxis: { padMax: 1.3 } }
  });
```

The documentation says "one array for each series," which I have. But the graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdJwU.png). My desired result is for the point labels to be (from left to right): fourteen, fifteen, thirty two, thirty three, forty one, forty two